# lightning events vs parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**Events are used to Communicate between components.** I'm unable to understand why I have to use events when I can pass parameters between components as attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When two components can "see" each other, you can **pass an attribute** as you mention or **call a method**:

> Use `<aura:method>` to define a method as part of a component's API.
>   This enables you to directly call a method in a component’s
>   client-side controller instead of firing and handling a component
>   event. Using  simplifies the code needed for a parent
>   component to call a method on a child component that it contains.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm?search_text=method

Events are good for **loose coupling**. When two components can't see each other, then events are better than doing a search by some kind of ID and then using an attribute or a method.